How to convert ticks liquidity to tokens amounts in Uniswap V3
I am trying to compute token amounts basing on ticks liquidity value for the USDC/WETH pair in Uniswap V3. I take pool and tick data from The Graph API https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v3. What I'd like to get - values like 208.2K and 20.56 from this screenshot.

The closest thing that I've found is ticks liquidity calculation algorithm in https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/154926/17095 (see point 3), I've replaced ticks with this data from The Graph API link mentioned above:
[
  { tickIdx: 193740, liquidityNet: -3613995902018273n },
  { tickIdx: 193800, liquidityNet: 15922075084830948n }
]

set:
const initialLiquidity = BigInt('1543530621931537245'); // Pool `liquidity` from The Graph API link
const currentTickIdx = 193743; // Current pool `tick` from The Graph API link
const stopTickIdx = 193800;

and got:
Computed active liquidity at tick 193860: 1559452697016368193

But I don't understand how to get tokens amount from this value.
